# Looping through results and changing value depending on distance

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Im trying to loop through an array of objects. I want to change the rating depending on the distance away. For example if the distance is 10-20 miles away the rating will drop.

This is what i have done but I'm unsure why its not working because I'm not getting any errors.

```
<script>

    var products = [{product:"Shoe", Rating:"4", Distance:"2"},{product:"Trousers", Rating:"5", Distance:"5"},{product:"Glasses", Rating:"3", Distance:"7"},{product:"Hat", Rating:"2", Distance:"10"}];
    var rating = products[1];
    var distance = products[2];

    for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (distance >= 0 && distance <=4)
            rating = rating+1;
        else if (distance >= 5 && distance <=10)
            rating = rating-1;
        else if (distance >= 11 && distance <=20)
            rating = rating-2;
        else if (distance >= 21 && distance <=100)
            rating = rating-3;
        else if (distance >= 101 && distance <=10000)
            rating = rating-4;
        else
            rating = rating;
        console.log(products[i]);
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: you already set the rating in the products array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I feel that you are missing. First is you loop through every list object and never update the rating variable. Second is that the distance and rating variables in the object are `string`s not `int`s so your comparison and operation will be off. And at the very beginning you assign rating and distance to an object instead of a value from an object.

I would change the variable assignment to inside the for loop, at `[i]` and then distance or rating. Also `parseInt` so you can compare as an `int`. Then update the rating after each iteration of the loop.

```js
var products = [{
  product: "Shoe",
  Rating: "4",
  Distance: "2"
}, {
  product: "Trousers",
  Rating: "5",
  Distance: "5"
}, {
  product: "Glasses",
  Rating: "3",
  Distance: "7"
}, {
  product: "Hat",
  Rating: "2",
  Distance: "10"
}];
var rating;
var distance;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  rating = parseInt(products[i]['Rating']);
  distance = parseInt(products[i]['Distance']);
  if (distance >= 0 && distance <= 4)
    rating = rating + 1;
  else if (distance >= 5 && distance <= 10)
    rating = rating - 1;
  else if (distance >= 11 && distance <= 20)
    rating = rating - 2;
  else if (distance >= 21 && distance <= 100)
    rating = rating - 3;
  else if (distance >= 101 && distance <= 10000)
    rating = rating - 4;
  else
    rating = rating;
  products[i]['Rating']=rating;
  console.log(products[i]);
}
```